# Unix - Standard input and output

Tags: unix, stream

```
$(($one/$zero)) 2> tasty.txt >> cat.txt
$(($one/$zero)) 2> tasty.txt >> cat.txt
```

My input

```
one=1

zero=0
```

Why the error is not getting redirected into tasty.txt, but gets printed?

Answer (score 0):

Because when you execute a command in $() it opens a new subshell.

```
:-:echo "one is $one and Zero is $zero" 
one is 1 and Zero is 0
:-:eval $one/$zero 2> error.txt
:-:cat error.txt
bash: 1/0: No such file or directory
```

When I execute the command in the present shell error is redirected to the file.

```
:-:$($one/$zero) 2> error_1.txt
bash: 1/0: No such file or directory
:-:cat  error_1.txt
```

When I execute the command in subshell error is redirected to standard output.

```
:-:$($one/$zero 2> error_1.txt) 
:-:cat error_1.txt 
bash: 1/0: No such file or directory
:-:
```

But when I redirect std error in a file inside subshell it is captured.